# Double integral of Periodic function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be periodic with period 1: $f(t+1)=f(t)$.

Is it correct to claim that:

$$\iint\limits_{[-1,1]\times[0,1]} |f(x+t)-f(-x+t)|\,dt\,dx=2\iint\limits_{[0,1]^2} |f(x+t)-f(-x+t)|\,dt\,dx$$?

My reasoning is that $\iint\limits_{[-1,1]\times[0,1]} |f(x+t)-f(-x+t)|\,dt\,dx\\=\iint\limits_{[-1,0]\times[0,1]} |f(x+t)-f(-x+t)|\,dt\,dx+\iint\limits_{[0,1]\times[0,1]} |f(x+t)-f(-x+t)|\,dt\,dx$

Thanks for any help. (this is an intermediate step in something I wish to prove)

Comment: Assuming $[-1,1]$ is the range of $t$, this looks correct. Experiment with $f(x)=\sin ( \frac{x}{2\pi})$: [Integral-1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+int+sin((x%2Bt)%2F(2pi))+-+sin((-x%2Bt)%2F(2pi))dt+dx+t%3D-1+to+t%3D1,+x%3D0+to+x%3D1) = [Integral-2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+int+2sin((x%2Bt)%2F(2pi))+-+2sin((-x%2Bt)%2F(2pi))dt+dx+t%3D0+to+t%3D1,+x%3D0+to+x%3D1).

Comment: @iamvegan Thanks for the tip